# How do I Get This Function to Delete Nodes of Circular Doubly Linked List more than Once? (C)

Tags: c, linked-list, circular-list

I have to delete every k node from a linked list. When this function is called with say, k = 2, it deletes the second node, but doesn't delete any more after that. Here is the function:

```
void remove(soldier* list, int n, int k)
{
    soldier* head = list;
    int counter = n;

    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    soldier *curr = head;
    soldier *prev1 = head;
    while (counter != 0) {

        if (curr->next == head && curr == head)
            break;

        displayList(head);

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            prev1 = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        if (curr == head) {
            head = curr;
            prev1 = head;
            while (prev1->next != head)
                prev1 = prev1->next;
            head = curr->next;
            prev1->next = head;
            list = head;
            free(curr);
        }

        else if (curr->next == head) {
            prev1->next = head;
            free(curr);
        }
        else {
            prev1->next = curr->next;
            free(curr);
        }
        counter--;
    }
}
```

When called

```
remove(front, n, k);
```

n = 5, k = 2, I get this output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 3 4 5
1 3 4 5
1 3 4 5
1 3 4 5
```

What should I do to get is so that another is deleted each line of output? Thanks.

Comment: You understand that when you modify a functuon parameter, like 'list', the passed argument  in the caller remains unaffected?

Comment: Why do you care about `n = 5` if you are just deleting the k*th* node in the list?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to delete the k<sup>th</sup> node from a doubly-linked circular linked-list, then as shown in you question, for example if the list contained:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

With `k=2`, you would want to delete `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 3, ...` until the list was empty. It is somewhat of a 2-part problem. (1) delete the k<sup>th</sup> node, and (2) increment the k<sup>th</sup> position so it is now points to  the k<sup>th</sup> node after the one you just deleted. That can be implemented in several ways. Probably the most pragmatic is to implement the delete k<sup>th</sup> node function, and then write a wrapper function if needed to update the counter so it will delete the next node in sequence.

With a pointer-to-pointer to the 1<sup>st</sup> node in list `l`, and the  k<sup>th</sup> node being the one to delete, you could do something similar to:

```
/** delete kth node in doubly-linked circular list from node *l
 *  returns pointer to new node at address of deleted node or NULL if
 *  list now empty.
 */
node_t *delkthnode (node_t **l, size_t kth)
{
    node_t  **ppn = l,      /* pointer to pointer to node */
            *pn = *l;       /* pointer to node */

    size_t n = kth ? kth - 1 : 1;   /* set no. to advance (1-based index) */

    if (pn == pn->next) {           /* last node left in list? */
        free (pn);                  /* free node */
        return *ppn = NULL;         /* set address for node to NULL */
    }

    while (n--) {                   /* loop to kth node */
        ppn = &pn->next;            /* update current address to next */
        pn = pn->next;              /* update current node to next */
    }

    *ppn = pn->next;                /* set current address to next node */
    (*ppn)->prev = pn->prev;        /* set current->prev to next->prev */
    if (pn->next == *l)             /* deleting tail node? */
        (*ppn)->prev->next = *l;    /* set new end->next to head */
    if (pn == *l)                   /* if current node is head */
        *l = *ppn;                  /* update list adddress to current */

    free (pn);      /* free node memory */

    return *ppn;    /* return pointer to new node at address of removed node */
}
```

(**note:** the above uses both a pointer to the node and the address for the current pointer to iterate and replace the node at the address to be deleted with the next node in the list, see [Linus on Understand Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/))

A semi-short example implementation would that tests the logic could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef NNODES
#define NNODES 10
#endif

typedef struct node_t {     /* list node */
    int data;
    struct node_t *prev, *next;
} node_t;

/** create new node initialize all members */
node_t *createnode (int v)
{
    node_t *node = malloc (sizeof *node);   /* allocate node */
    if (!node) {                            /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        return NULL;
    }
    node->data = v;                         /* initialize members values */
    node->prev = node->next = NULL;

    return node;    /* return new node */
}

/** add node at end of list */
node_t *add (node_t **l, int v)
{
    node_t *node = createnode (v);      /* allocate node */
    if (!node)                          /* validate allocation */
        return NULL;

    if (!*l) {                          /* 1st node is self-referencing */
        *l = node;                      /* set head to node */
        (*l)->prev = (*l)->next = node; /* set prev & next to node */
    }
    else {                              /* otherwise - insert as new tail */
        node->prev = (*l)->prev;        /* node->prev is list->prev */
        node->next = *l;                /* node->next is head */
        (*l)->prev->next = node;        /* tail-next is node */
        (*l)->prev = node;              /* head->prev is node */
    }

    return node;    /* return new node */
}

/** delete kth node in doubly-linked circular list from node *l
 *  returns pointer to new node at address of deleted node or NULL if
 *  list now empty.
 */
node_t *delkthnode (node_t **l, size_t kth)
{
    node_t  **ppn = l,      /* pointer to pointer to node */
            *pn = *l;       /* pointer to node */

    size_t n = kth ? kth - 1 : 1;   /* set no. to advance (1-based index) */

    if (pn == pn->next) {           /* last node left in list? */
        free (pn);                  /* free node */
        return *ppn = NULL;         /* set address for node to NULL */
    }

    while (n--) {                   /* loop to kth node */
        ppn = &pn->next;            /* update current address to next */
        pn = pn->next;              /* update current node to next */
    }

    *ppn = pn->next;                /* set current address to next node */
    (*ppn)->prev = pn->prev;        /* set current->prev to next->prev */
    if (pn->next == *l)             /* deleting tail node? */
        (*ppn)->prev->next = *l;    /* set new end->next to head */
    if (pn == *l)                   /* if current node is head */
        *l = *ppn;                  /* update list adddress to current */

    free (pn);      /* free node memory */

    return *ppn;    /* return pointer to new node at address of removed node */
}

void dellist (node_t *l)
{
    if (!l) {
        puts ("list-empty");
        return;
    }

    node_t *iter = l->next;

    do {
        node_t *victim = iter;
        iter = iter->next;
        free (victim);
    } while (iter != l);
    free (l);
}

void prnlist_fwd (node_t *l)
{
    node_t *iter = l;

    if (!l) {
        puts ("list-empty");
        return;
    }

    do {
        printf (" %d", iter->data);
        iter = iter->next;
    } while (iter != l);

    putchar ('\n');
}

void prnlist_rev (node_t *l)
{
    if (!l) {
        puts ("list-empty");
        return;
    }

    node_t *iter = l->prev;

    do {
        printf (" %d", iter->data);
        iter = iter->prev;
    } while (iter != l->prev);

    putchar ('\n');
}

int main (void) {

    node_t  *list = NULL;
    int kth = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < NNODES; i++)    /* loop NNODES times */
        add (&list, i+1);               /* add node with i+1 value to list */

    prnlist_fwd (list);                 /* print original list fwd/rev */
    prnlist_rev (list);
    putchar ('\n');

    while (delkthnode (&list, kth++)) {
        prnlist_fwd (list);             /* print updated list fwd/rev */
        prnlist_rev (list);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    dellist (list);
}
```

Where above you just build the list with integer values `1-10` for the node values and then call:

```
    int kth = 2;
    ...
    while (delkthnode (&list, kth++)) {
        prnlist_fwd (list);             /* print updated list fwd/rev */
        prnlist_rev (list);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
```

which acts as the wrapper for continually deleting every other node in the list until the list is empty (which is the purpose of having the function return a pointer to the node that remains at the address where the node was deleted, or `NULL` if the list is now empty)

**Example Use/Output**

Printing the original list (both forward and reverse) and then printing the updated list (both forward and reverse) until the all second nodes in the list have been deleted would result in:

```
$ ./bin/lldcir_del_kthnode
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 1

 1 3 5 6 7 8 9 10
 10 9 8 7 6 5 3 1

 1 3 5 7 8 9 10
 10 9 8 7 5 3 1

 1 3 5 7 9 10
 10 9 7 5 3 1

 1 3 5 7 9
 9 7 5 3 1

 1 5 7 9
 9 7 5 1

 1 5 7
 7 5 1

 1 5
 5 1

 1
 1

list-empty
```

Or in your exact case with the list as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`:

```
$ ./bin/lldcir_del_kthnode
 1 2 3 4 5
 5 4 3 2 1

 1 3 4 5
 5 4 3 1

 1 3 5
 5 3 1

 3 5
 5 3

 5
 5

list-empty
```

Hopefully this is what you intended. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. (note: you may have to adjust the tests and add additional validations to catch all corner cases -- this is left to you)